# cant find lopencv_core when install caffe

Tags: opencv, caffe

```
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp
CXX tools/compute_image_mean.cpp
CXX tools/train_net.cpp
CXX tools/device_query.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.cpp
CXX tools/finetune_net.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
CXX tools/convert_imageset.cpp
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
CXX tools/caffe.cpp
CXX tools/test_net.cpp
CXX examples/siamese/convert_mnist_siamese_data.cpp
CXX examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.cpp
CXX examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp
CXX examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.cpp
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
AR -o .build_release/lib/lenter code hereibcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l -lopencv_core
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:573: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I got this error when compile caffe. I have built opencv3.2.0 and this is libopenc_core.so in /usr/local/lib. I have spent a whole day on it and still don't know why. I really need help

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory `/usr/local/lib` to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`. 
 After this run the command `sudo ldconfig` in order for the changes to take effect and then recompile caffe